# Rails 3.2: Running CoffeeScript on the show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a show action, and would like to call a function once it's finished loading. The function relies on jQuery being loaded, as well as the rest of application.js.

I tried creating show.js.coffee, with this in it:

```
SomeClass.doSomething '<%= @thing.description %>'
```

... but the show.js.coffee is never loaded and therefore never executed. How do I do this?

Comment: Where is the show.js.coffee file?  In your app/views or app/assets?  Did you try adding it to application.js?

Comment: I want it to be in app/views/thing/show.js.coffee. I don't know if that's correct, but it's where other coffeescript for views goes, so it makes sense that it should be there too.

Comment: To clarify, @John (correct me if I'm wrong Tim), this is a view template using Rails' built in JS rendering on an action. I'm not sure if `.coffee` files outside of `app/assets` get ERB'd automatically; have you tried adding `.erb` to the file extension? Do you get any JavaScript errors? Any console output if you use `<% Rails.logger.info 'testing' %>` or similar?

Answer (score 5):

Version 3.2 of the [coffee-rails](https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails) gem adds support for JavaScript requests in the `app/views` directory:

> Also adds support to use CoffeeScript to respond to JavaScript requests (use .js.coffee views).

**NOTE:** Move `gem coffee-rails` out of `group :assets`.

Just call the `things#show` action like normal (`remote: true`), and make sure there is a file named `app/views/things/show.js.coffee`.

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.12 and there was no need to move gem coffee-rails outide the assets group

Comment: Seems odd to place js/coffee scripts under the views folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but it sounds like there are two things: 1) there needs to be some DOM event that triggers execution, and 2) ERB and controller context (the `<%= @thing.something %>`) are only present and processed in views. In this case, it sounds like document.ready is the event.  So assuming you have `SomeClass` defined in CoffeeScript somewhere where it has already been loaded, your `show.js.coffee` file (which is executing in a javascript/DOM context) might be something like

```
$ ->
  SomeClass.doSomething $("#thing_something").val()
```

It's possible that you could get the ERB part by adding something like this in your `show.html.erb` view

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  $ ->
    SomeClass.doSomething '<%= @thing.description %>'
</script>
```

Not sure about that...